# jquery: set min max input in option type number

Tags: jquery, numbers, max, min

I have this part of code

```
<input type="number" min="2" max="10" step="2" id="contact" oninput="new_sum">
```

In the field I can insert  a number > 10 and < 2.

How can I limit it?

Comment: It is already limited. What exactly do you mean by "How can I limit it?"

Comment: I believe they are asking if you type a number into the input field. The limit isn't handled.

Answer (score 44):

add an `onchange` function and set the value if it's out of the range.

```js
 $(function () {
       $( "#numberBox" ).change(function() {
          var max = parseInt($(this).attr('max'));
          var min = parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
          if ($(this).val() > max)
          {
              $(this).val(max);
          }
          else if ($(this).val() < min)
          {
              $(this).val(min);
          }       
        }); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numberBox" type="number" min="2" max="10" step="2" id="contact"  />
```

Comment: you're right, I had a typo - `($this)` instead of `$(this)`. I've updated the answer and fiddle. Check them out.

Comment: yes it's correct now.Is it possible block the input text? it should work only with the buttons

Comment: I'm not at a computer, but I would try setting the read only CSS property to true.

Comment: I'd use `keyup` rather than `change` so it can't be typed in.

Comment: Just comparing two input values gave faulty result. Using Parseint($(this).Val()) worked for comparing two input numbers on input.

Answer (score 12):

A simpler and dynamic way for **not allowing** the user to **type or paste values outside the interval** nor any other non-numeric character (without the need for manually parsing or detecting keys):

```js
$('input[type=number]').on('mouseup keyup', function () {
  $(this).val(Math.min(10, Math.max(2, $(this).val())));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" step="2" id="contact">
```

If this specific event is only needed for a particular input use the `id`, i.e. `$('#contact').on(...)`.
*Explanation*: these [Math functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) compare with `Infinity` in the absence of an argument.

*Note*: `mouseup` can also be used to prevent the user to paste or use the arrows with the cursor.

Answer (score 5):

The approach I've used here (though I've created a plugin to do so) is to check whether the entered value is in the range defined by the `min` and `max` attributes, if it *is* we keep that value; if *not* we test whether the entered value is less than the `min` value, if it is then we set the value *to* the `min` value and if not (implying that the value must be greater than the `max`) we set the value to the `max` attribute:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.restrict = function () {
        // returns the collection returned by the selector, over which we iterate:
        return this.each(function(){
            // binding a change event-handler:
            $(this).on('change', function(){
                // caching the 'this' (the current 'input'):
                var _self = this,
                    // creating numbers from the entered-value,
                    // the min and the max:
                    v = parseFloat(_self.value),
                    min = parseFloat(_self.min),
                    max = parseFloat(_self.max);
                // if it's in the range we leave the value alone (or set
                // it back to the entered value):
                if (v >= min && v <= max){
                    _self.value = v;
                }
                else {
                    // otherwise we test to see if it's less than the min,
                    // if it is we reset the value to the min, otherwise we reset
                    // to the max:
                    _self.value = v < min ? min : max;
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#contact').restrict();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LdvWy/).

This is somewhat naive, in that the `restrict()` plugin doesn't test whether the `<input>` element's type is of `number` (yet).

**Edited** to add a slight sanity check to check that the element is, in fact, of `type="number"`:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.restrict = function () {
        return this.each(function(){
            if (this.type && 'number' === this.type.toLowerCase()) {
                $(this).on('change', function(){
                    var _self = this,
                        v = parseFloat(_self.value),
                        min = parseFloat(_self.min),
                        max = parseFloat(_self.max);
                    if (v >= min && v <= max){
                        _self.value = v;
                    }
                    else {
                        _self.value = v < min ? min : max;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LdvWy/1/).

Comment: thank you!.Is it possible block the input text? it should work only with the buttons

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, imagine how difficult that would be in, for example, a smart-phone or tablet.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a generic function to do this on any input step elements --

```
 $(function () {

    var limitInput = function () {
        var value = parseInt(this.value, 10);
        var max = parseInt(this.max, 10);
        var min = parseInt(this.min, 10);

        if (value > max) {
            this.value = max;
        } else if (value < min) {
            this.value = min
        }
    };

    $("#numberBox").change(limitInput);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z9c9e/)

Comment: @user2519913 - Sorry - Updated my answer and the fiddle as well.

Answer (score 1):

jquery set min max input (all type)

set attribute min & attribute max in tag input

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<input type="tel" class="form-control text-right ltr" data-min_max data-min="0" data-max="100" data-toggle="just_number" />
```

you can change min & max

data-min="0" data-max="100"

Jquery

```
$(document).on('keyup', '[data-min_max]', function(e){
    var min = parseInt($(this).data('min'));
    var max = parseInt($(this).data('max'));
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(val > max)
    {
        $(this).val(max);
        return false;
    }
    else if(val < min)
    {
        $(this).val(min);
        return false;
    }
});

$(document).on('keydown', '[data-toggle=just_number]', function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

EXAMPLE : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h06dbgda/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write just with jquery:

```
$('#contact').prop('minLength', 2);
$('#contact').prop('maxLength', 10);
```