# Restrict input type="number" to its min or max if it is out of range

Tags: html, input, numbers, restrict

I have the below code

```
<form:input type="number" min="1" max="4" size="5" value="1" path="n" name='n' placeholder="<5" style="height:25px;width:60px"></form:input>
```

if a user enters a value in the textbox out of range then it should reset to its nearest min or max value, for example if user enters in textbox as less than 1 then it should get reset to 1, if he enters more than 4 then it should get reset to 4.

Please advice if we have any other tag instead of using input tag to restrict

There is a solution already which is not working for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict user to put value in range in html input (type = number)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825843/restrict-user-to-put-value-in-range-in-html-input-type-number)

Comment: No it is on key press. I need restriction on directly entering in the textbox

Comment: Any way to disable textbox edit and should use only the keypress?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually input type=number only handles and not allows user to submit the form if the entered number is not in range

Answer (score 10):

This solution might be what you're after: [jquery: set min max input in option type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353748/jquery-set-min-max-input-in-option-type-number)

```
$(function () {
    $( "input" ).change(function() {
        var max = parseInt($(this).attr('max'));
        var min = parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
        if ($(this).val() > max)
        {
            $(this).val(max);
        }
        else if ($(this).val() < min)
        {
            $(this).val(min);
        } 
    });      
});
```

@Caspian also provided a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ddk67/75/

Comment: This works but I was not expecting jQuery. Actually input type=number only handles and not allows user to submit the form if the entered number is not in range

Comment: @AaronLavers in this solution, it accepts 'e' as number :) you should use parseInt() on input value and isNaN() in a else-if statement ;)

Answer (score 10):

It would be nice if HTML5 actually prevented values from being entered because preventing the value from being submitted only, does not satisfy all use cases.

In such cases I would call the following function on keyup.

```
function imposeMinMax(el){
  if(el.value != ""){
    if(parseInt(el.value) < parseInt(el.min)){
      el.value = el.min;
    }
    if(parseInt(el.value) > parseInt(el.max)){
      el.value = el.max;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage example

```
<input type=number min=1 max=4 onkeyup=imposeMinMax(this)>
```

This will reset the value to the max value if the user types in a greater value, and will reset it to the min value if the user types in a lesser value.

Comment: Probably should be onblur rather than onkeyup, in case the minimum is more than a single digit

Comment: This answer also accepts 'e' as a number.

Comment: This does not seem to work for my use case. I have input type with ```min = 12``` and ```max = 30```. Lets say I want to set value 15. As soon as I type value 1, it will automatically set the value to 12. If I try to backspace to remove the digit "2", it will automatically set to 12 again.  I think this example only works if min is > 0

Comment: UPDATE. Replacing onkeyup with onblur fix my issue.